# sqlplus does not execute the query if it is called by a ssh external connection

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-plugins, sqlplus

I have a script lying into a Unix server which looks like this:

**mainScript.sh**

```
#some stuff here
emailScript.sh $PARAM_1 $PARAM_2
#some other stuff here
```

As you can see, mainScript.sh is calling another script called **emailScript.sh**.

The **emailScript.sh** is supposed to perform a query via sqlplus, then parse the results and return them via email if any.

The interesting part of the code in **emailScript.sh** is this:

```
DB_SERVER=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
EVENT_DATE=$4
LIST_AUTHORIZED_USERS=$5
ENVID=$6
INTERESTED_PARTY=$7
RAW_LIST=$(echo "select distinct M_OS_USER from MX_USER_CONNECTION_DBF where M_EVENT_DATE >= to_date('$EVENT_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') and M_OS_USER is not null and M_OS_USER not in $LIST_AUTHORIZED_USERS;" | sqlplus -s $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$DB_SERVER)
```

As you can see, all I do is just creating the variable `RAW_LIST` executing a query with `sqlplus`.

The problem is the following:

1. If I call the script **mainScript.sh** via command line (PuTTy / KiTTy), the `sqlplus` command works fine and returns something.
2. If I call the script **mainScript.sh** via an external job (a `ssh` connection opened on the server via a Jenkins job), the `sqlplus` returns nothing and takes 0 seconds, meaning it doesn't even try to execute itself.

In order to debug, I've printed all the variables, the query itself in order to check if something wasn't properly set: everything is correctly set.

*It really seems that the command* `sqlplus` *is not recognized, or something like this*.

Would you please have any idea on how I can debug this? Where should I look the issue?

Comment: Can you run `sqlplus` with its full path? on the remote machine. Check the path from `which sqlplus` on the remote machine and invoke it with its full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider few things here. While you are running the script, from which directory location you are executing the script? And while you are executing the script from your external application from which directory location it is executing the script. Better use full path to the script like `/path/to/the/script/script.sh` or use `cd /path/to/the/script/` command to go to the script directory first and execute the script. Also check execute permission for your application. You as an user might have permission to execute the script or sql command but your application does not have that permission. Check the user id for your application and add that into the proper group.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it!

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, wish you all the very best. :-)